# Will weight exercises help mitigate wrist pain?

Tags: strength, wrist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is working out a healthy alternative to combat RSI (Repetitive Stress Injuries)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1131/is-working-out-a-healthy-alternative-to-combat-rsi-repetitive-stress-injuries)

Long hours in front of my laptop have weakened my hands and wrists and caused me to have a repetitive strain injury. I used to play football and work in construction. Weight-lifting was a part of my daily routine. Back then, my joints were strong and resilient and able to withstand trauma associated with sports.

I've never had a problem with my wrists until I started programming. I'm sure that my best bet is to try to strengthen my wrists and fingers by lifting weights as a type of physical therapy. My fear is that I will do weight exercises that will exacerbate the problem rather than get rid of it, and I'm wondering if anyone has had luck with any specific exercises. My back and shoulders are fine but my hands are not.

Comment: specifically I'm wondering about this....http://lghttp.5679.nexcesscdn.net/8042CE/fg-magento/media/catalog/product/cache/8/image/400x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/c/wcurl.jpg

an exercise where you hold a bar with a rope a weight attached to it, twisting the rope onto the bar (isometric exercise)

Comment: This question might be relevant too: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/how-to-strenghten-my-wrists